# in j2me canvas, how to reduce Image size?

Tags: image, java-me, canvas, sprite, lcdui

I am doing project in j2me for Nokia s60 devices
This project has lot of PNG images and Sprite images there. All images are unique, so my project jar size is near 10MB. If I compress image, image does not look good, so I want to put actual image in this project.
in J2me Canvas, is there any image encoding to reduce size but keep good quality or not?

Comment: No, you cant reduce size without losing quality.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly,try some tools like PNGGauntlet and so on. It can compress your png files with less quality lose. The second method is obfuscate your project.

Answer (score 1):

You should obfuscate your project. it reduces the jar size also encrypt your source code. Also  resave your images in photoshop cs3 not 5 as web images

Answer (score 0):

Do you check [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)? Its main purpose is to reduce the size of the PNG IDAT datastream by trying various compression levels and PNG filter methods.